# Laravel PHP uninstallation

Tags: php, laravel, uninstallation

I was trying out Laravel framework. I installed Node.js, Composer etc.
Now I have to 'go back' and practice on my older project where I used basic PHP with xampp and as a text editor I used brackets. I copied my old project to xampp/htdocs/ . I set up my browser with localhost/epo(the name of my project folder) and it gave me these errors:

```
    1/1
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Or if its easier to see the screen shot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEJZQ.png

I'm a beginner, but as far as I can tell, there are some leftovers from my Laravel installation. How can I fix this? I only want to do my old project with pure PHP and nothing else, but I can't seem to fix this.

Comment: laravel does not install its own php. try to look at `hosts` file

Comment: 404 Not found. Did you checked your routes file?

Comment: Make a copy of your project and completely wipe out the content of the `htdocs` directory. Then copy back your project files only. I hope you don't have installed Laravel on top of your old project files...

Comment: I fixed it guys. Just reinstalled xampp completly. Thank You very much for all the help! How foolish of me not to try that in the first place